# Using controllers to retrieve data from multiple tables

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, models, controllers

Currently I have a SQLite database with 3 tables; accounts, interactions and checklists. In the accounts controller I have it pulling data from all three tables to display the content. 
The accounts table has multiple accounts stored in it and the interactions table is linked through a foreign key (account_id). 
 On the accounts page I want only the interactions that have the same account id to be listed on the corresponding account.
at present I have them appearing in the view, but the view is currently listing every interaction in the table, I know this is because I'm using `Interaction::all()` But I've been unable to figure out how exactly to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

- please note, I'm not using models.
- Each account can have many interactions

accountController

```
    public function show($id)
{
    $account = Account::find($id);

    $checklists = Checklist::where('account_id', $id)->first();
    //$interactions = Interaction::get();
    $interactions = Interaction::all();
    //dd($interactions);


    return view('account_view')->with('account', $account)->with('checklists', $checklists)->with('interactions', $interactions);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have model relationships set up in your models? if so, you can load the related objects using `with`:

```
$account = Account::with('interactions', 'checklist')->find($id);
return view('account_view', compact("account"));
```

In your blade file:

```
$account;
$account->checklist; //your checklist with account_id of $account->id
$account->interactions; //your interactions with account_id of $account->id
```

To set up the relations in your Account model:

```
public function checklist(){
  return $this->hasOne(Checklist::class);
}
public function interactions(){
  return $this->hasMany(Interaction::class);
}
```

Comment: No, I currently am not using models. Is there a way to do this without models?

Comment: You must be using models if you are using things like `Checklist::where()` or `Interaction::all()` - those would be your model classes. Do you have a file `Account.php` which is a class that extends `Model`?

Comment: I have them created. But the files currently have nothing in them

Comment: so if the checklists only have one per account, that would be `$this->hasOne(Checklist::class)` correct?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many this is the best way to access models that have ID relationships in your database.  An account `hasMany` checklists, and a checklist `belongsTo` an account.  You can very simply access the related models as if it was just an object property.

Comment: yes @MLJezus it would be `hasOne` and you would make the function called `checklist` instead of `checklists` - edited answer

Comment: Can I ask why I am doing `return $this->hasMany(Interaction::class)` opposed to what is suggested in the link you provided which is `return $this->hasMany('App\Interaction')`

Comment: @MLJezus It is up to your preference.  I like to use `Interaction::class` because if you decide to change your model namespace later (like I keep mine in `App\Models\Interaction`) then your IDE can automatically update the `import App\Interaction` to `import App\Models\Interaction` for you.  With just a string, it will cause an error.  Again, it is your preference, same effect